# What's the best standalone photo stitching software available for the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-rec, photos, panorama, photo-stitching

I'm aware this topic has cropped up before.

However most of the answers were Windows specific. Right now I'm using the software that came with my camera and it works fine. However, it has one serious drawback : it doesn't process pictures taken with cameras of other brands. I'm mostly stitching pictures together to create panoramas. Price is not an issue and I've tried Photoshop's built-in pano tool but it's a little bit elementary.

Auto-Stitching and HDR support is really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Related (the other ones you talk about): http://superuser.com/questions/15946/how-to-make-a-cyclorama, http://superuser.com/questions/8047/open-source-panorama-maker-for-windows and http://superuser.com/questions/41684/panoramic-picture-stitchers (starting to wonder about some merging in these ones).

Comment: @Gnoupi Agree with merging. There should be a definitive one-stop place for this photo-stitching/panorama topic (all platforms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out virtually all trial versions of existing photo stitching software, I've to got to say [Autopano Giga](http://www.autopano.net) hits the sweet spot. It has everything I was looking for : first class panorama editing and an overwhelming and intimidating set of parameters to control the rendering of your panorama and even HDR support. And I'm not even using the Pro Edition.

[image: Autopano Giga]

I did further research before buying it and I was astounded to find out that the Pro edition was used to create the [world's largest stitched image](http://70gigapixel.cloudapp.net/index_en.html); a gigantic 70 gigapixel image that's a whopping 200 GB in terms of file size.

If Autopano Giga can create a 70 gigapixel image of Budapest; well it's definitely more than adequate for my needs.