# How to stitch planar images? (pixel exact, no bluring, no deformation)

Tags: image-processing, panorama, hugin

i have a sets of images A

Each image (a_i) is a slice of an huge computer generated map-image M_A. 
Each image a_j in A overlaps with at least one other image a_k in A.
There is no distortion, blur or color difference they overlap pixel perfect and are completely planar.

- i need to stitch them together = map M_A.
- After that i need to find the difference between M_A and an other map-image M_B (gimp)

the last part is no problem:
I can put them in 2 layers in Gimp an set one to 'Differece'

the tricky part is the lossless stitching

so:

- How do i stitch the overlapping images together without blurring or deformation?

i tried Hugin ([How to make a cyclorama](https://superuser.com/questions/15946/how-to-make-a-cyclorama)) - i like it - but it seems it is all about inexact images (taken by Cameras). It forced me to choose a focal length. And after 3h of computation i ended up with a projection of planar objects on a sphere, witch were then projected back to a plane for rendering...

Comment: Your meta question points to a similar question marked as a duplicate of others.  Those, in turn, chain to additional, similar questions.  I didn't exhaustively follow every chain, but I quickly got to 18 answers in addition to the one you mention.  There is a little overlap, but numerous answers don't suffer from the shortcoming you cite.  Given the extensive existing answers, I don't see value in asking what appears to be the same question again.  Without clarifying a uniqueness here, this will waste people's time responding with identical answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a cyclorama](https://superuser.com/questions/15946/how-to-make-a-cyclorama).  See also https://superuser.com/questions/44463/what-is-the-best-photo-stitching-software-available and follow the chains of mentioned questions.